# How to produce Flutter Text Field that underline incorrect words with suggestion provided?

Tags: flutter, textfield, flutter-widget

A picture is worth a thousand words, let me show you what I tried to achieve:
[image]

The solution could be using Flutter built-in widget or third-party widget.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Text.rich() method (or the [RichText Widget](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/RichText-class.html)) to achieve what you want.
The following snippet corresponds to your screenshot.

```
  return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Text.rich(
          TextSpan(
            text: 'I lost ',
            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24),
            children: <TextSpan>[
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'Password.',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  )),
              TextSpan(
                  text: ' ',),
              TextSpan(
                  text: 'What do?',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                  )),
              // can add more TextSpans here...
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for quick response. I aware about the Rich Text widget, but what I need is for text field input, not display.

Comment: What kind of words would you like to be underlined ? A set of words you defined or the words containing grammatical errors ?

Comment: The words can be two separate sets of words in a sentence or a sentence in a paragraph. Perhaps I need to look into Rich Text Editor instead of simple text field to implement this feature. Hope this clarify.